# Is it possible to use multiple "character sets" in a visual studio 2010 project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, unicode

As you know, in visual studio 2010(c++) we have noset, unicode and MBCS character sets, and we can set it by menus or by preprocessor directive like #define _UNICODE. 
   I'm working on a project, it has a file that uses MBCS characterset to produce information (in fact it parse a html file!), and other files in the project work by unicode character set to support assian languages. I've test it by adding #define _MBCS for the file and #define _UNICODE for main file, but received some compiler errors. 
   Now is there anyway to solve this problem?

Comment: What are the errors that you get?

Comment: @ivan Along with a [MCVE] of course.

Comment: for example like this: atlconv.h(776): error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'LPCTSTR' to 'LPCOLESTR'

Comment: Are you saying that data is in different character encodings.  Or are you saying that your source files are in different character encodings?

Comment: The file get html file as an array of bytes. And Analyse it. If I use unicode, I should convert it to wchar_t that is time consuming and may be not safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LPCTSTR is the pointer to TCHAR (string).  It maps to either LPWSTR (wide char string) or LPCSTR (ansi string) depending if the `_UNICODE` or `UNICODE` defines were set.  All of this TCHAR stuff was a holdover from the Windows 9x days when the earlier versions of Windows didn't have Unicode support in their APIs, but developers wanted to target compiling for both NT and 9x.  All of this should be well deprecated by now.

My advice - get rid of all your TCHAR code and be explicit when using ANSI vs. UNICODE strings.

1. Convert all your project settings to Unicode.
2. Explicitly convert all LPTSTR, LPCTSTR, TCHAR, variables to be explicitly, LPWSTR, LPCWSTR, or WCHAR.  Or when explicitly dealing with ANSI strings: LPSTR (char*), LPCSTR (const char*), or CHAR (char).
3. Be explicit when calling Win32 APIs.  Use the "A" version of APIs when you want to process an ANSI string (e.g. CreateWindowA vs. CreateWindowW).
4. [MultiByteToWideString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072(v=vs.85).aspx) and [WideStringToMultiByte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374130(v=vs.85).aspx) are your friends.

Comment: Thanx. In case number 3, for example the file uses BYTE pTag[1024]; array or _tcsupr((_TCHAR*)pTag) and _tcscmp((_TCHAR*)pTag, state) and _tcscpy(result, (_TCHAR*)state); functions, and using Unicode makes results to be uncorrect!

Comment: Same thing for C runtime functions.  Either use `strcpy / strcmp` or `_wcscpy / _wcscmp` explicitly.  The fact that the existing code was explicitly casting is scary to begin with.

Comment: Thanx. and what about "BYTE pTempData[FRAME_BUFFER_SIZE]; InternetReadFile(hURL, pTempData, numberOfBytesToRead, &numberOfBytesRead);" function? pTempData contains html file! And I think converting it to wchar_t does not work!

Comment: InternetReadFile will copy the **bytes** of the HTML file into your byte buffer. After InternetRealFile returns, you'll likely have a set of ascii bytes in your pTempData.  So at this point you should null terminate this array and copy to an allocated `char*` or `char[]` buffer.  It's up to you if you want to convert this string to Unicode - it depends on what you want to do and/or the source enccoding of that HTML file.

Comment: Thanx. I think I must try it again!