# Header of _tcsstr

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Hello i have a copied a little code from the internet and it uses `_tcsstr` and i was wondering what the header of that method is so that i can use it...

```
    HANDLE GetHandleFromProcessPath(TCHAR* szExeName, DWORD& dwPID)
{
    HANDLE hExeName = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    HANDLE hSnap = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32;
    pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE != hSnap)
    {
        if (Process32First(hSnap, &pe32))
        {
            do
            {
                //!!! Attention pe32.szExeFile always return exe file name. not window title.
                if (NULL != _tcsstr(pe32.szExeFile, szExeName))
                {
                    hExeName = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, pe32.th32ProcessID);
                    dwPID = pe32.th32ProcessID;
                    break;
                }
            } while (Process32Next(hSnap, &pe32));
        }
    }


    return hExeName;
}
```

SO:
In what header is the method `_tcsstr(pe32.szExeFile, szExeName)` ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/strstr-wcsstr-mbsstr-mbsstr-l Although unless you plan to compile multi-byte and unicode versions of your app you should use the correct one rather than the TCHAR mess.

Comment: It's better if you just get out of the `TCHAR` world entirely. Pick ANSI or unicode (prefer unicode) and go with it. You can have unpleasant surprises if you don't know if you're using wide characters or not.

Comment: So, you copied random code off the internet and now it does not work and you want us to fix it? Sorry, but no. Maybe do another random internet search for the header you need or *maybe* try understanding what you are doing and read the documentation of whatever library you are using and *stop* copy'n'paste'ing random code off the internet - that's *not* the way to learn C++.

Comment: @J. Dzi learning C++ would go a *long way* towards fixing your problem. But whatever; keep learning from random code snippets and answers to questions that don't tell the full story. Come back in 10 years and tell me how well that worked out for you.

Comment: Recommended reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming

Comment: "SO: In what header is the method _tcsstr" - `git grep` or similar (if not a `git` repository - like plain `grep -R`) should tell you quickly. As would/should reading the documentation of whatever provided that function.

Comment: Use the wide character version always.

Comment: Btw; just saying. This is completely non-portable.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It seems silly to worry about a substring search being non-portable when all of this code is win32 specific.

Comment: @Retired Ninja I was not actually commenting on the substring matching as much as the complete non-portability of the code in general. In *my* book this whole thing classifies as "crappy platform specific code that should not exist except *maybe* inside platform specific `ifdef`s".. but that may be just me.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer: `#include <tchar.h>`

Long answer: **Stop using TCHAR** altogether.  `TCHAR` was a Microsoft invention way back when it was common for code to cross compile for both ANSI based Windows 95/98 and Unicode based Windows NT(2000/XP).  These days `TCHAR` is a rather antiquated concept.  C/C++ projects targeting Windows should just have UNICODE and _UNICODE defined by default.  Instead of using `strstr` or `tcsstr`, just use `wcsstr`.  Replace all your `TCHAR` and `LPTSTR` references with `wchar_t` and `LPWSTR` as appropriate.

Comment: It seems I've answered this question more than once:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33712101/104458