# Cannot construct CString from a char

Tags: c++, char, c-strings

In VS2008, I try to construct a CString from a char, as follows:

```
CString str = CString(_T('A') + 5);
```

But will get the following compile error:

error C2440: '' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'CString'

I belive TCHAR and int is exchangable in C++, so why it refuses to accept the TCHAR type parameter to construct a CString?

The purpose of the line is to construct a CString with only one character _T('F'). Not to get "A5".

I try to understand how the compiler processes the code, as follows:

1. It will first promote _T('A') to an integer.
2. It will add the integer value of _T('A') by 5.
3. It will get a new integer and cannot find a way to convert it back to TCHAR, which can be used as input parameter for CString constructor.

Comment: stop using tchar. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50572941/104458

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but if you want to get `A5`, then `str.Format(L"%c%d", 'A', 5);` will do the trick.

Comment: @MaxVollmer, CString has a constructor which can construct from a TCHAR

Comment: @Blaze, I am trying to construct a CString with one character _T('F').

Comment: I stand corrected.

Comment: Then you likely want `CStringA((char)('A' + 5))` or `CStringW((wchar_t)(L'A' + 5))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CstringT` constructors that accept a `char` or a `wchar_t` are `explicit`. See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/reference/cstringt-class?view=vs-2019#cstringt).

The `explicit` specifier in C++ means that the compiler is not allowed to do an implicit conversion of the parameter(s). See also [explicit specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit).

Thus the compiler cannot (is not allowed to) implicitly convert the `int` value to `char` or `wchar_t`.

*(Note that this depends on the flag `_ATL_CSTRING_EXPLICIT_CONSTRUCTORS` being set. Without the flag being set, the constructors are not explicit, but then it's ambiguous which constructor to chose.)*

So you need to explicitly cast the parameter to `char` or `wchar_t`, depending on what you want:

```
CStringA str = CStringA(static_cast<char>('A' + 5));
```

or:

```
CStringW str = CStringW(static_cast<wchar_t>(L'A' + 5));
```

Answer (score 1):

CString will not implicitly convert an int to CString. However you can try like so

```
CString str; 
char c = 'A';
int i = 5;
str.Format(L"%c%d",c, i);  // unicode assumed
```